# bootstrap dropdown / Text data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I have created a dropdown list for department using ASP.net framework web form and bootstrap -

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="ddl_dept">Primary Department<span style="color: Red">*</span></label>
   <select class="form-control" id="ddl_dept" tabindex="5">
      <option value="">Please Select a Department</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

and trying to get the item from a database. here is my code in C#

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DivCode,DivDesc FROM Z_Division"))
      {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.Connection = con;
         con.Open();
         ddl_dept.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         ddl_dept.DataTextField = "DivDesc";
         ddl_dept.DataValueField = "DivCode";
         ddl_dept.DataBind();
         con.Close();
      }
   }
```

The error message I get is `ddl_dept` doesn't exist in the current context.
when I use the same dropdown using  `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_dept" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>` it works.
Also the ID reference from the input text control doesn't recognise from coding `<input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="txt_firstName" tabindex="2">`. I mean `txt_firstName` is not recognizing from the coding page. I don't know what I am missing!

Comment: The way you can resolve this is to use the asp controls, and then look at how those controls render to HTML (F12 dev tools in your browser, and inspect the HTML)., and then replace those controls with that HTML  For one, you're missing the name attribute on your HTML elements (which could be necessary, depending on the way you're posting your data).  For a second thing:  asp controls can render Id's that are different than what you see in the control  -- it depends on your setup.  You'll be able to tell when you look at the rendered HTML of a control

Comment: `when I use the same dropdown using <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_dept" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> it works.`. Well, that's how webforms works... Either use that or use MVC/Core

Comment: Does it mean, we cannot use Bootstrap in ASP.NET framework web form?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that ASP .NET renders **WebControls** as HTML, which means that if you want to keep the "**bootstrap style**" or work the DOM through some language on the client you can (you can verify this through the inspector of the browser). However I think there are two solutions to your question depending on the approach:

**Solution 1:**
The easiest and if your purpose is to preserve the Bootstrap style with the DropdownList control, it is to use the CssClass tag (and add a small part of the C # code of the method to display that selection criteria option item):

ASPX Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ddl_dept">Primary Department<span style="color: Red">*</span></label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_dept" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

**C# Code:**

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DivCode,DivDesc FROM Z_Division"))
   {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.Connection = con;
      con.Open();
      ddl_dept.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      ddl_dept.DataTextField = "DivDesc";
      ddl_dept.DataValueField = "DivCode";
      ddl_dept.DataBind();
      con.Close();
   }
}

//Add this line
ddl_dept.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Please Select a Department", "0"));
```

**Solution 2:**
The other solution without using the ASP .NET control, is through a call to ASPX WebMethod using AJAX, which I do not recommend because WebMethod must be static which means that it is difficult to reference other controls or variables (not static) and makes it hard to maintain in the long run (what I hate most about ASP .NET):

**C# Code:**
You need create this web method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string WebMethodLoadDropdownList()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DivCode,DivDesc FROM Z_Division"))
       {
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmd.Connection = con;
          con.Open();
          dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
          con.Close();
          
          // Return List converted in JSON object
          return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.AsEnumerable().ToList());
       }
    }
}
```

**ASPX Code:**

Add this script section in yout aspx form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("YourAspxNameForm.aspx/WebMethodLoadDropdownList") %>',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: null, // Nothing
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                //console.log(msg.d); this line print the result from the webmethod

                if (msg.d) {

                    var obj = JSON.parse(msg.d);

                    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                        //console.log(value.Code);
                        //This line add the new item in the dropdownlist
                        $('#ddl_dept1').append(new Option(value.DivDesc, value.DivCode));
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error JSON Data');
                }

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `runat="server"` attribute in your `select` markup.

So it should be:

```
 <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="ddl_dept" tabindex="5">
      <option value="">Please Select a Department</option>
 </select>
```

The reason your getting that error is .NET Framework doesn't recognize any control which are not decorated by `runat` server. This is like telling .NET framework to consider every control decorated withh `runat="server"` as a server control and perform actions on it.

Comment: This gives an error: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Comment: Then you can use asp control itself. <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddl_dept"> </DropDownList> just use this and build your project.